# Specific use of Eval to parse a function call with Groovy

Tags: groovy, eval

I'm receiving in groovy a string in this format:

```
"function_name(columnOne,columnTwo)"
```

What I need to achieve is to call the function I have defined in my script (named function_name) and passing to the function "columnOne" and "columnTwo" as String.

Is it possible to achieve that directly with some form of Eval? without the need to split the string and extract the two names?

My function_name will get those 2 column from a dataset, with something like

```
val1 = a['columnOne']
```

that's why I need that sequence of character treated as a string.

Any Idea or workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DelegatingScript`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/DelegatingScript.html) can be used with [`propertyMissing`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing):

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

class MyDSL {
    // every property missing will just be returned as a string
    def propertyMissing(final String name) { name }
    // your function with any string arguments
    void function_name(final String... args) {
        println "Called function_name($args)"
    }
 }

CompilerConfiguration cc = new CompilerConfiguration()
cc.setScriptBaseClass('groovy.util.DelegatingScript')
GroovyShell sh = new GroovyShell(getClass().classLoader, new Binding(), cc)
DelegatingScript script = (DelegatingScript)sh.parse("function_name(Between,The,Burried,And,Me)")
script.setDelegate(new MyDSL())
script.run()
```

Comment: Your code work well, but what If I don't know what am I going to receive in place of columnOne? My issue is that the string will be dynamic and will depend on the whoever is calling the script. I could receive function_name(XXX,ByStander) or function_name(Vel,Dorment). Any Idea

Comment: @SeraphimFoA Should then e.g. `Vel` be handled like `'Vel'` (invent a new String)?

Comment: Exactly. whatever come turn it into a string.

Comment: i changed the answer to use `promertyMissing`

Comment: Impressive. Groovy level over 9000!!!! I'm really new in Groovy and for me it still looks like magic, not coding!!!